# updateMany based on other field in mongodb

Tags: mongodb, mongo-java, mongo-java-driver

I have two documents

```
/* 1 */
{
    "lastUpdated" : ISODate("2019-01-01T01:01:20.201Z"),
    "content" : "someText01",
}

/* 2 */
{
    "lastUpdated" : ISODate("2020-11-11T16:11:20.202Z"),
    "content" : "someText02",
}
```

Now I would like to update documents - create new field as copy of lastUpdated field;

In robo3T I can do something like this

```
db.getCollection('someDocuments').update({}, 
    [
        {"$set": {"byMongoQuery": "$lastUpdated", }}
    ],
        {"multi": true}
)
```

And it works.
Now I would like to do same using java code (mongo-java-driver 3.9.0)
And I do something like

```java
mongodb.getCollection("someDocuments").updateMany(Document.parse("{}"), Document.parse("{$set: {'byJavaApi': '$lastUpdated'}}"))
```

mongodb is instance of com.mongodb.client.MongoDatabase

Final results is like this:
[image]

Value is set as plaintext for some reason.

I'm using
Mongodb 4.2.6
mongo-java-driver 3.9.0

Questions:

1. How to set this field using java code. I would prefer updateMany as there is a lot of those records
2. Why results are different. I was expecting there is some common engine in mongdb that executes it. And this is exactly the same query.

Comment: Maybe dumb, but have you tried removing the single quotes around ' $lastUpdated ' ?

Comment: removing single quotes results in wrong sytax 
```org.bson.json.JsonParseException: JSON reader was expecting a value but found '$lastUpdated'.```

Comment: You are using an aggregation pipeline in the  _update_ statement (which is run from a tool). The MongoDB Java code is not (thats the reason why the value is set as "plaintext").

Answer (score 0):

Your update is using the **MongoDB v4.2** feature of [updating using a pipeline](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/update-documents-with-aggregation-pipeline/index.html). You can code this using **MongoDB Java Driver v3.11** ***or higher***. Update a field using value from another field:

```
Bson query = new Document();
List<Bson> updatePipeline = Arrays.asList(Fiters.eq("$set", Filters.eq("byMongoQuery", "$lastUpdated")));
UpdateResult result = collection.updateMany(query, updatePipeline);
```